# SASS compiler failed with exit code 1

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm following the official getting started with NativeScript/Angular and working on [this repo](https://github.com/NativeScripting/course-exercise-files-nativescript-angular-getting-started-guide/tree/master/chapter2/02_07_end/Groceries) when I do `tns run android` I get the following:

> Executing before-watch hook from /Projects/course-exercise-files-nativescript-angular-getting-started-guide/chapter2/02_07_end/Groceries/hooks/before-watch/nativescript-dev-sass.js
>   Found peer node-sass
>   No input file was found.
>
> SASS compiler failed with exit code 1

My node version is: 10.15.1 on a Mac OS Mojave 10.14.2

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.Groceries",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "7.0.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "7.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "1.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "6.3.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.18.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~7.0.0"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

I tried many suggestions on other issues discussion but without success.

Answer (score 0):

You will see that error only when you don't have even one SCSS file in your project. Add at least one SCSS file to your project and the error should go away.